# How to make maven-jaxb2-plugin to ignore generating class if it is already exist in my project source

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am using maven jaxb2 plugin to generate java classes from xsd.I have a requirement that it should not generate the class if class already exist in my source.

```
Is there anyway can we configure to ignore the pojo generation if it is already exist.
```

Example:

Customer class already exist in my source and i dont want to regenerate again so it should be ignored by plugin even if we process the customer.xsd

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
             <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>0.12.1</version>
         <executions>
         <execution>
         <goals>
         <goal>generate</goal>
         </goals>
         </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
         <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
  <!--          <generatePackage>com.test</generatePackage>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/src/main/java</generateDirectory> -->


    enter code here

         <schemaIncludes>
         <include>*.xsd
         </include>
         </schemaIncludes>
         </configuration> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is not possible to accomplish.

Taken from the plugins' [Wiki](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Up-To-Date-Checks) page, you can control "what else" (apart from the default files like pom.xml) controls if your files are out of date and need to be recompiled, but you cannot exclude any of the default ones mentioned in "The up-to-date check algorithm".